# How to create a yocto recipe that installs only the libraries to the target machine rootfs and all headers and libraries to the sdk host rootfs?

Tags: sdk, cross-platform, yocto, bitbake

When I want to put files in the target rootfs, I just need to use

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/lib
    install -m 0755 ${COMPILED_LIBRARY_DIR}/mylibrary.so ${D}/lib/
}
```

But how can I get all headers and files that are only required for development included in the host rootfs of the SDK that can be generated with populate_sdk?

---

## Update:

- The library that I'm trying to install is [pistache](https://github.com/oktal/pistache)
- The poky version is 1.7.3
- Which I think it's using cmake 2.8.12.
- Pistache has a requirement of minimum cmake 3.1.3
- I cannot update poky because we received the source from the supplier of the chip, with all the .git folders removed from poky, meta-openembedded, etc. And the build directory contains some compiled scripts that generate the image to flash the board, so I am nor sure that if I actualize poky the scripts will still work.

---

## I tried:

- Patching the required minimum cmake version to 2.8.12 (I know that it was a really bad solution).

  - But it didn't compile either.
- Generating the sdk, installing it in my development host, and crosscompile pistache with a newer cmake. Then uploading the resulting files to a repository and manually install them all with do_install()

  - But the board keeps rebooting and the resulting sdk lacks the .a (static library) file in the cross rootfs and all the files in the target rootfs.

Comment: If you stick to canonical install destinations, this should be done for your: things under /usr/include or such go into the -dev packages, and those are by default included in the SDK.

Comment: So if I understood it well, I should install them all in do_install and put all dev files in FILES-${PN}-dev?

Comment: If you don't do anything fishy, you don't even have to that manually. Feel free to carefully inspect bitbake -e for your package, looking fir FILES_${PN}-dev. It should be set automatically.

Comment: @LetoThe2nd, I am probably doing something fishy, I updated the question with the probable fishiness sources.